Set up Greens function given eigenfunctions
I have an exercise for uni where I need to derive the greens function for a given PDE, the pde is as follows:
$$
\partial_t u = \partial_x^2 u - u \\
\partial_x u(0,t) = 0, \  \partial_x u(L,t) = 0\\
u(x,0) = u_0(x)
$$
In my (very limited) understanding of the Greens function it is based off of eigenfunctions, which in this case I have derived to be
$$
\phi_n(x) = c_n \cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{L}x\right) \text{  with  } \lambda_n = \frac{\pi^2n^2}{L^2} - 1
$$
If I understand correctly, to fromulate the Greens function i need an eigenfunction conformint to only the first boundary condition and an eigenfunction only conforming to the second boundary condition. But is it not the point of these eigenfunctions that they all conform to both?? Any help at all with this would be greatly appreciated!!

what about the function $d\sin(\frac{\pi}{2L}x)$? It is a solution to the linear equation but only matches the right boundary. In general, you need to match $A_n\cos(\frac{\pi n}{L}x)+B_n\cos(\frac{\pi n}{L}x)$ to the left boundary value and $C_n\cos(\frac{\pi n}{L}x)+D_n\cos(\frac{\pi n}{L}x)$ to the right boundary value and you'll notice that the coefficients are not necessarily the same.

Hint: $$G(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\phi^*_n(x)\phi_n(y)}{\lambda_n}$$
